# Is there a way to fix loose or less enunciated speech?

Tags: voice-over, voice-manipulation

For a particular voice-over, the speaker...doesn't exactly have "slurred" speech, but they have some kind of...loose speech, it's not a distinguishable accent, they simply don't open their mouth very wide to enunciate words properly.

For instance, they might say "propa-ly" instead of "prop**ER**-ly" or "I jus want to thank you..." instead of "I jus**T** want to thank you...". Is there any technique for sharpening speech to get rid of that?

Answer (score 1):

Short of speech therapy, the realistic answer is no. If the problem was just lower frequency in the speech making it sound muddy then sure you can roll off the lower frequency, but from your description the problem is enunciation. There are not any mainstream techniques from the audio processing side of things to fix this other than dubbing over it.

The exception of course is software in development that will do speech replacement (Adobe is one company working on this), however I do not believe any is yet commercially available.

Comment: Great answer. Getting it right at the source remains the best method!